# How can I get start date and end date of each period in sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table rows like this.

```
status     start      end
32         1/1/2017   1/2/2017
32         1/2/2017   4/2/2017
1          4/2/2017   6/3/2017
1          6/3/2017   9/5/2017
32         9/5/2017   19/5/2017
32         19/5/2017  22/6/2017
```

And I wanna group rows to

```
status     start      end
32         1/1/2017   4/2/2017
1          4/2/2017   9/5/2017
32         9/5/2017   22/6/2017
```

How can I do using SQL?
thank you for all help.

Comment: in what condition you need to group it? You did not group it by status since from the sample result you have 2 record for status 32. You can use Min() for start and Max(date) for end, and lastly you need to group it based on your condition

Comment: Am I correct in thinking that the goal is to get un-interrupted periods grouped together? So if you had 1 (1/7/2017-1/9/2017) and 1 (1/10/2017 - 1/15/2017) they would be separate groups? 

Your given data doesn't have gaps so some clarity would be helpful.

Comment: @theo Yes, your idea is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can easily do this one in one step. Maybe if you resort to some ugly recursive CTE or a very long chain of CTEs or nested sub-queries. Basically you need to reconfigure your dataset so you can tell the beginning and end of a period.

Assumptions:

- Any gap means a period is ending and a new period is beginning
- There are no overlapping periods. (i.e. 1 (1/7 - 1/12), 1 (1/10 - 1/20) )

I'm going to go with SQL-Server syntax because it's what I'm most comfortable with, but these operations should be something you could do in most sql environments with a little modification. (I'm using a temp table and CTE's, but you could use sub-queries)

```
create table dbo.[Status] (
    [status] int,
    [start] date,
    [end] date
)

insert into dbo.[Status] ([status], [start], [end])
values
    (32,    '20170101', '20170201'),
    (32,    '20170201', '20170204'),
    (1,     '20170204', '20170306'),
    (1,     '20170306', '20170509'),
    (32,    '20170509', '20170519'),
    (32,    '20170519', '20170622')


create table dbo.Result (
    PeriodID int identity, -- to make grouping and self-referential joins easier
    Status int,
    start date,
    next_start date null,
    [end] date null
)

select * from dbo.[Status]
-- This will get you all the periods and their start dates
;with cteExcludeTheseRows(status, start) as (
    -- These are the records where the Start date matches an end date for the same status group. As a result these aren't real periods, just extensions.
    select S.status, S.start
        from [Status] S
        join [Status] Prior on S.Status = Prior.status and S.start = Prior.[end]
)
insert into dbo.Result (status, start)
    select
        S.status,
        S.start
    from [Status] S
        left join cteExcludetheserows Exclude on S.status = Exclude.status and S.start = Exclude.start
    where Exclude.status is null

-- Reference the temp table to get the next start period for your status groups, that way you know that the end date for that period has to be less then that date
;with cteNextStart (PeriodID, next_start) as (
    select
        R.PeriodID, 
        next_start = min(next.start)
        from dbo.Result R
        join dbo.Result next on R.status = next.status and r.start < next.start
        group by R.PeriodID
)
update R
    set R.next_start = next.next_start
    from dbo.Result R
    join cteNextStart next on R.PeriodID = next.PeriodID

-- Now get the end date for each period by looking back at your main status table
;with cteEnd (PeriodID, [end]) as (
    select 
        R.PeriodID,
        [end] = max(s.[end])
        from dbo.Result R
        join [Status] S on R.status = s.status and S.[end] between R.start and isnull(R.next_start, '99991231')
        group by R.PeriodID
)
update R
    set R.[end] = [end].[end]
    from dbo.Result R
    join cteEnd [end] on R.PeriodID = [end].PeriodID


-- And finally, here you have your result set
select
    status,
    start,
    [end]
    from dbo.Result 
    order by start, status

drop table dbo.[Status]
drop table dbo.Result
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I am very grateful.

Answer (score 1):

see  also
[demo](http://rextester.com/HLPD94056)

```
SELECT  * FROM aaa a
where a.sstatus != (select top 1 b.sstatus from aaa b
                                where b.start_date < a.start_date
                                order by b.start_date desc);
```

Comment: The output of this query in the demo doesn't remotely match the results desired according to the question, unless I completely misunderstood what the OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
   you may try this:

   CREATE TABLE #STATUS 
    (
        [STATUS] INT,
        [START] DATE,
        [END] DATE
    )

    INSERT INTO #STATUS
     (
      [STATUS], [START], [END]
     )
    VALUES
        (32,    '20170101', '20170201'),
        (32,    '20170201', '20170204'),
        (1,     '20170204', '20170306'),
        (1,     '20170306', '20170509'),
        (32,    '20170509', '20170519'),
        (32,    '20170519', '20170622')

    SELECT 
      A.STATUS
     ,A.[START]
     ,B.[END] 
    FROM #STATUS A 
    LEFT JOIN #STATUS B 
    ON A.[STATUS]=B.[STATUS]
    AND A.[END]=B.[START]
    WHERE B.STATUS IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: This will only work when there are exactly 2 records in each given status for each period. If there is only one record or more than 2 records it will not correctly handle all periods.